# How to escape a cookie to cause split response?

Tags: cookies, response-splitting

A website takes the following request and sets the "_Add_User" as a cookie in the response:

Request

```
GET /cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_Add_User HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.example.com/myaccount/home
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DC: slc-a-origin-www-2.example.com
Content-Length: 55293
X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 127
X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 1011
Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:47:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_Add_User
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
```

I can change "_Add_User" to "TEST" and cookie will be changed to "TEST".

Is it possible to escape the cookie and cause split response? Can I exploit this behavior in any way?

Comment: You can only exploit it as a splitting attack if you can cause encoded values to be decoded into the cookie value, e.g. passing %0D%0A into the URL producing a raw CR+LF in the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

While the exact answer will depend on the technology you're using to process the request, the odds are that you can't split the header because modern frameworks have protection against [response splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting).

To exploit you need to find or create a vulnerable server that somehow allows the user to inject a CRLF into a cookie. Frequently this would be done with the HTML encoding of `%0D%0A` but the exact encoding mechanism will vary depending on the vulnerability you have found. For example, if the server processes backslash escapes, `\n\r` would be appropriate.